# For loop not working in function on strings column

Tags: python, string, pandas, function, for-loop

I'm working on a real estate dataset where I have a column with strings referring to apartment floor (e.g. "1° di 4 piani", first of 4 floors in italian).
My idea is to loop through each element of the column to clean it using this loop to check if it's working:

```
    for f in df['floor']:
        try:
            if '1°' in f:       
                print(1)
            else:
                print(0)
        except TypeError:
            pass
```

Everything seems to work until I use this kind of code in a function to apply:

```
def floor_edit(floor):
    try:
        for f in floor:
            if '1°' in f:       
                return 1
            else:
                return 0
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

Then I apply the function:

```
df['floor'] = df['floor'].apply(floor_edit)
```

Column populates with all None values.
i know this is probably a very basic error but I've been stuck here the entire day.

Comment: sorry, typing error in the post (not in the actual code)

Comment: why are you looping over floor? You are already using the apply function.

Comment: There is no return value for the function on except... probably there is the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to loop if you create a function for `apply`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"floor":["15","20","ABCDE","1° di 4 piani"]})

def floor_edit(s):
    if '1°' in s:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

df["new"] = df["floor"].apply(floor_edit)

           floor  new
0             15    0
1             20    0
2          ABCDE    0
3  1° di 4 piani    1
```

But better is to use `str.contains`:

```
df["found"] = df["floor"].str.contains("1°").astype(int)

           floor  found
0             15      0
1             20      0
2          ABCDE      0
3  1° di 4 piani      1
```